Percentage of grouped records over entire population in Telerik report
I need to create a Telerik report using the Report Designer to show the gender composition of a population over the years like this:



Year
Female
Male
Total





25275
17965
43240


2020
58.45%
41.55%
100%



26674
18357
45037


2021
59.23%
40.76%
100%



27295
18473
45768


2022
59.4%
40.36%
100%



I have a datasource with records containing year and gender, and I have grouped my rows by year, and my columns by gender (except the last one of course). My problem is, how can I access the total number of records for each year from inside the group to get the percentage for the Male and Female columns?
I haven't found a way to do it yet. If I use the format option to show it as percentage, it just shows the count multiplied by 100 with a % sign following. I also thought for a second that this entry may be useful, but alas.
